# How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and remove the duplicate items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays

```
var array1 = [{firstName:'John', age:32, email:'xyz1@email.com'}, {firstName:'Jack', age:40, email:'xyz2@email.com'}];
var array2 = [{firstName:'Jen', age:29, email:'abc1@email.com'}, {firstName:'Jack', age:40, email:'xyz2@email.com'}];
```

I would like to merge the two arrays and get the below output

```
var array3 = [{firstName:'John', age:32, email:'xyz1@email.com'}, {firstName:'Jack', age:40, email:'xyz2@email.com'}, {firstName: 'Jen', age: 29, email: 'abc1@email.com'}];
```

Would like to know best way to merge two arrays in JavaScript so that I get only the unique items from each array?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You can do this using Rest Operators, the Set Object and JSON methods:

```
[ ...new Set([...a1, ...a2].map(JSON.stringify)) ].map(JSON.parse);
```

---

### Example

```js
var array1 = [{firstName:'John', age:32, email:'xyz1@email.com'}, {firstName:'Jack', age:40, email:'xyz2@email.com'}];
var array2 = [{firstName:'Jen', age:29, email:'abc1@email.com'}, {firstName:'Jack', age:40, email:'xyz2@email.com'}];

function joinArrays(a1, a2) {
 return [ ...new Set([...a1, ...a2].map(JSON.stringify)) ].map(JSON.parse);
}

console.log(joinArrays(array1, array2));
```

### Explanation:

You combine Arrays by using Rest Operators:

```
[...a1, ...a2]
```

You turn the Objects into Strings with `JSON.stringify`:

```
[...a1, ...a2].map(JSON.stringify)
```

You place these Strings into a `Set`. Sets do not allow duplicate Primitive Values( *strings, numbers, etc* )

```
new Set([...a1, ...a2].map(JSON.stringify))
```

You use the Rest Operator to place the `Set` into an `Array`

```
[...new Set([...a1, ...a2].map(JSON.stringify))]
```

You map the Array using `JSON.parse` to turn the strings back into Objects, minus duplicates.

```
[ ...new Set([...a1, ...a2].map(JSON.stringify)) ].map(JSON.parse);
```

Comment: This will remove any functions, Sets, Maps, or any other complex data types from objects in `array1` & `array2`. It will also simply fail if there are any circular dependencies, for example `array1[0].self = array1[0]`

Comment: @Olian04 Do you see any functions or complex data types outside of the base Objects in the arrays that the OP provided?

Comment: That is not a good enough reason to provide a faulty answer. OP has provided (as per the rules of StackOverflow) a small verifiable EXAMPLE. In other words, not necessarily the exact data that will be used in the real world.

Comment: @Olian04 You can have your perception, but if you give an example of an array filled with primitive values why would anyone *assume* differently? That's absurd. We'd be type-checking answers all day long. This is not a "faulty" answer in context. When you hear hoof beats assume a Horse, not a Zebra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** method to merge without duplicates and ensure the mapping is efficient in-case the arrays are long

First you create a map of the elements in the first array with the key **firstName**. This will save on performance for large arrays/lists

```
const array1Map = array1.reduce(
  (state, payload) => ({...state, [payload.firstName]: payload})
)
```

Then you create a new array by merging the two arrays but check against **array1Map** for duplicates using the **reduce** function again

```
const mergedArray = array2.reduce((state, payload) => {
  if (!array1Map[payload.firstName]) {
    return [...state, payload]
  }
  return state
}, array1)
```

The new array is a combination of the 2 arrays without duplicates

```js
var array1 = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    age: 32,
    email: 'xyz1@email.com',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jack',
    age: 40,
    email: 'xyz2@email.com',
  }
]
var array2 = [{
    firstName: 'Jen',
    age: 29,
    email: 'abc1@email.com',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jack',
    age: 40,
    email: 'xyz2@email.com',
  }
]

const array1Map = array1.reduce(
  (state, payload) => ({ ...state,
    [payload.firstName]: payload
  })
)

const mergedArray = array2.reduce((state, payload) => {
  if (!array1Map[payload.firstName]) {
    return [...state, payload]
  }
  return state
}, array1)

console.log(mergedArray)
```